# Uso el plugin "boostrap-dialog" en fiddler y funciona, pero en mi sistema no

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-3, diálogo

Acá un ejemplo básico del código que utilizo:

```js
BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: '¡Hola!'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

El problema es que a mi me lanza este error:
[image: error]

**NOTA:** entiendo que `BootstrapDialog` lo esta reconociendo como una variable. Pero ¿Por que en fiddler si funciona y en mi sistema no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He probado tu código, tal como te lo pongo aquí:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>  


          </head>
          <body>


        <script>
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            message: '¡Hola!'
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Funciona !.

Pruebalo en tu máquina, debe funcionar, entonces el problema son tus librerias o el orden en que las cargas.

Saludos,

Comment: Es como dices: ***el problema esta en el orden***, usando tu ejemplo moví las librerías en el orden en el que están en mi sistema; ***bootstrap.min.js*** y ***bootstrap-dialog.min.js*** van justo antes de finalizar el `body`. Aclaro: en mi sistema ***bootstrap.min.js*** debe ir después de todo para que funcione correctamente mi sistema y ***bootstrap-dialog.min.js*** tiene que ir después de ***bootstrap.min.js*** para que pueda funcionar. ¿Alguna sugerencia? :-/

Comment: Prueba ubicar el bootstrap-dialog.min.js, después de bootstrap.min.js, debería funcionar. Si no, publica tu html para revisar

Comment: Moví ***bootstrap-dialog.min.js*** después de ***bootstrap.min.js*** pero yo tengo esas librerias antes del `body` que cierra; en el ejemplo que tu colocas y el cual es funcional las etiquetas tienen que ir en el `head`.

Comment: Amigo pude ordenar las librerías que tengo, di y di hasta que posicione ***bootstrap.min.js*** en el `head`. Gracias hermano.

Comment: :) que bueno, saludos